Mockito throws NPE when mocking class which extends abstract groovy class
Any methods Mockito 4.11.0 tries to stub on a class which extends an abstract groovy (2.4.21) class result in NPE for me. The following example is how I am trying to stub two methods on the Demo class, but since Demo extends an abstract class all I get are NPE, even for the method "bar()" native to Demo. Removing the word "abstract" causes the test code to execute green. Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong here and how I can mock classes which extend groovy abstract classes?
import org.junit.Test
import org.mockito.Mockito

import static org.mockito.Mockito.when

class Demo extends Foo {

    boolean bar() {
        return false
    }
}

abstract class Foo {
    Boolean isValid() {
        return true
    }
}

class DemoTest {

    @Test
    void testMe() {
        Demo demo = Mockito.mock(Demo.class)
        when(demo.isValid()).thenReturn(false) // will throw NPE
        when(demo.bar()).thenReturn(false) // will throw NPE
    }
}


Does it help to mark Demo, Foo, bar, and isValid as public? What version of the JDK are you using? I'm wondering if this is an artifact of synthetic methods used to access members that would otherwise be package-private.

@JeffBowman in Groovy, public is the default.

Can you please add the stacktrace from the NPE (assuming it throws somewhere inside Mockito or Groovy)

Maybe not an answer to your question but a sanity check. I ran the same code (added some semicolons) as Java with the same Mockito version (4.11.0), and it ran without throwing.
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

class Demo extends Foo {

    boolean bar() {
        return false;
    }
}

abstract class Foo {
    Boolean isValid() {
        return true;
    }
}

public class DemoTest {

    @Test
    public void testMe() {
        Demo demo = Mockito.mock(Demo.class);
        when(demo.isValid()).thenReturn(false); // fine
        when(demo.bar()).thenReturn(false); // fine
    }
}


correct, this is a groovy issue, I was unable to reproduce the issue in java.

You are 2 (almost 3) major Groovy versions behind. Maybe you could update?
